# FooterView for grid view

Tags: android, gridview, footer

I want to add footer view to GridView in android as we can add to ListView. Since it is not available in Grid View, I added a loading layout at bottom of screen, and a grid view above it. Loading layout becomes visible when we scroll grid view till end. But when loading layout becomes visible, on scrolling upwards, it remains visible. How this can be customized in a way similar to footer of list view. Any help will be highy appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to use **TemplateField** containing HTML Table?

Comment: No. I have to use grid view... in table view m not able to provide horizontal and vertical spacing easily.

Comment: **TemplateField** is an element in GridView, you may learn how to use it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317953/get-information-from-gridviewrow-using-row-index/20325283#20325283 You could make footer by <tfoot> of <table> tag, learn that here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tfoot.asp

Comment: i edited my question... I forgot to mention that i am working on android

Comment: https://github.com/lalit3686/ListViewLoadingItems

Comment: @LalitPoptani: Its with list view.. i know about footerView in list view. but i want to implement such with grid view in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid View doesnot have footer similar to listview. Its workaround used was: Add a view having progress dialog at bottom of screen below gridview and manage its visibility.